# Traversal from multiple vertices

Tags: arangodb

Is there any way to execute graph traversal from multiple vertices via HTTP?

As I can see in the documentation for the `/_api/traversal` endpoint, I can specify just a single start vertex.

I need to find multiple paths between two sets of vertices with many conditions like filters, sorting etc.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript-based graph traversals are deprecated and only support a single start vertex.

You can execute traversals via AQL instead (`/_api/cursor` endpoint).

For multiple start vertices, you can put a loop around your traversal query:

```
FOR start_vertex IN start_vertices
    FOR v, e, p IN OUTBOUND start_vertex @collection ...
```

```
FOR vertex IN [ "foo/bar", "baz/bark" ]
  FOR v, e, p IN OUTBOUND vertex @collection ...
```

A working example is shown in the [AQL documentation](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/aql/examples-and-query-patterns/traversals/).